# Matrix group isomorphic to R

Tags: matrices

Given the set G=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}, where a,c ∈R*, b ∈R and its subgroup H=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a^m\end{bmatrix}, where a ∈R*, b ∈R and m ∈Z, show that the factor group G/H is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of real numbers.

I started with proving that H is normal subgroup of G, therefore its left and right cosets are equal. I tried using **Theorem on homomorphisms** which says that if **ϕ(G) -> R** is homomorphism and **ker(ϕ)=H**, then the factor group G/H is isomorphic to (R,`*`).

My idea was to define homomorphism between determinants and real numbers, such that if **ϕ(det(g1)`*`(det(g2)) = r1`*`r2 = ϕ(det(g1))`*`ϕ(det(g2))**, where g1,g2 ∈G and r1,r2 ∈R. The next step is to show that **ker(ϕ)=H**. But I don't see a way to show that a number such as a`*`a^m is mapped into the neutral element(which is 1 in real numbers). So maybe, my approach is not correct but I don't have any clue of another.

Looking forward for your advice!

Comment: Is $m$ fixed?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the function
\begin{align*}
f \ : \ G \quad & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^\times \\
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
 0 & c
\end{pmatrix} & \longmapsto \frac{a^m}{c} .
\end{align*}

Comment: This was exactly the piece I was missing. Thank you so much :)